# "Got a result missing the "id" property" - Zapier

Tags: zapier

I want to make an app on zapier. Every process I have done clearly according to zapier request. My each process got success by zapier like API authentication and all. When I run my app on zapier I get authenticate, but at last it gives an error

> " Got a result missing the "id" property ".

What should I do? I think zapier want id property in the front position of the array, but during authentication my element in array got fluctuate and I got id in below position.

Answer (score 4):

There's more info about that message here: https://zapier.com/developer/documentation/v2/ZDE009/

Basically, you need to return an array of objects from your trigger, and each item in the array must have an "id" property.

> in the front position of the array

the order doesn't matter, since all of the objects need one.